# Installing Ximera to a CENTOS server

Tags: centos

I have a naked CENTOS server to which I would like to install the XIMERA package.

https://github.com/kisonecat/ximera

When I follow the steps given in the README file, I do fail to generate a folder named MATHQUILL at some step.

Are there anybody here who has a naked CENTOS server which they can use to install XIMERA properly. I would love to see the commands they used to do this installation properly.

Answer (score 0):

It's because they don't have that on bower.json file, I am not familiar with Ximera but take a look at bower.json bile

$ sudo vi /opt/ximera/bower.json

```
{
    "name": "ximera",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "dependencies": {
        "requirejs": "*",
        "almond": "*",
        "moment": "*",
        "lex": "https://github.com/aaditmshah/lexer.git",
        "jquery": "*",
        "less": "*",
        "jquery-ui": "*",
        "eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "*",
        "bootstrap": "3.3.4",
        "underscore": "1.6.0",
        "socket.io-client": "*",
        "font-awesome": "*",
        "sly": "*",
        "isotope": "*",
        "jquery-fullsizable": "*",
        "threejs": "https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js.git",
        "pagedown-bootstrap": "https://github.com/tchapi/pagedown-bootstrap.git",
        "syntaxhighlighter": "https://github.com/alexgorbatchev/syntaxhighlighter.git",
        "js-quantities": "*",
        "codemirror": "3.22.0",
        "skulpt": "*",
        "async": "*",
        "math-expressions": "https://github.com/kisonecat/math-expressions.git",
        "JavaScript-MD5": "*"
    }
}
```

There is only math-epxression Please ask the Ximera guys about the Mathquill